# Insert Footer/Header to pdf - PHP class mPDF

Tags: php, class, pdf, mpdf

How do I insert a footer on all sides?

`$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter($paticka);`-> Inserted in the last side

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify the page margin_bottom to leave enough room for the footer.
margin_bottom is the distance in mm from the bottom of the page for text to force a new page.
margin_footer is the distance in mm from the bottom of the page where the footer will be bottom-aligned.

```
$mpdf = new mPDF('', 'A4', '', '', $margin_left, $margin_right, $margin_top, $margin_bottom, $margin_header, $margin_footer);
```

http://mpdf.bpm1.com/forum/comments.php?DiscussionID=228

Edit: The above link appears to be old. I believe this is the new link:
http://www.mpdf1.com/forum/discussion/228

Comment: That does not help at all. The footer is still added only to the last page of the document.